# Replacing a request URL before page load with a Safari extension

Tags: javascript, replace, safari, webkit, safari-extension

I'm writing a Safari extension for personal use that modifies URLs from a certain website to make extremely small thumbnails viewable properly. The URLs are in the following format:

```
https://static.example.com/data/thumb/eb68634f5a5e3959e03be2af7c0b88ab.png
```

However, I want to strip out the `thumb/` from the URL before load, making it load the original, full size image, which will then be displayed differently using an injected stylesheet (which is already working).

I understand that the `beforeload` listener may be able to help me, but I have been unable to find adequate documentation on how I would go about essentially rewriting requests while on this website.

Getting the existing URL and changing it is completed; I am using the following testing code:

```
document.addEventListener("beforeload", handleBeforeLoadEvent, true);

function handleBeforeLoadEvent(event)
{
    if(event.url.match(/https:\/\/static.example.com\/data\/thumb\/(.+)/g)) {
        console.log(event.url.replace("thumb/", ""));
    }
}
```

Which outputs, as expected, URLs of this style:

```
https://static.example.com/data/eb68634f5a5e3959e03be2af7c0b88ab.png
```

But it still doesn't *set* the `event.url` to a new value. I can use `event.preventDefault()` to *cancel* the request, but I need to change the URL.

I hope someone can help me out with this! Bonus points if it could potentially, in theory, also work in Firefox and Google Chrome web browsers, since I use these browsers regularly.

Answer (score 1):

Property `event.url` is read-only. But something like this should work:

```
document.addEventListener('beforeload', function (evt) {
  if (evt.target instanceof HTMLImageElement) {
    if (/https?:\/\/static\.example\.com\/data\/thumb\//.test(evt.url)) {
      evt.preventDefault();
      evt.target.src = evt.target.src.replace('/thumb', '');
    }
  }
}, true);
```

That is, you make use of the event's `target` property, first to test if the target is an image, and if so, to change the image's `src` property.

Comment: That works; but I just had a serious problem - sometimes the original is not a PNG. The thumbnail is always a PNG. Do you know if there's any way to 'ping' JPG, PNG and GIF all to see if they are the extension?

Comment: No. If you're really determined, you could try loading each of those image possibilities invisibly and then reveal the one that loads (using the `load` event) and discard the other ones.